# Interface between activity and fragment becomes null automatically

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an activity with a menu button and two buttons. I have three fragments Frag_A, Frag_B, and Frag_C. By default, I am loading the activity with the fragment Frag_A. Based on clicking different buttons in the activity, I switch between the fragments.

For the fragment to access the activity buttons, I have created an interface BasicClickListener and I have made the activity implement the interface.

```
public interface BasicClickListeners {

    void onMenuClick();

    void goToFragment2();

    void goToFragment3();
}
```

I have implemented two methods in all fragments:

```
public synchronized void registerBasicListener(BasicClickListeners listener) {
    basicClickListeners = listener;
}

private synchronized void unregisterBasicListener() {
    basicClickListeners = null;
}
```

So, whenever I launch a fragment through the activity, I call registerBasicListener() method from the activity. And on all fragments' onDestroy(), I am calling unregisterBasicListener.

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterBasicListener();
    }
```

Now if I wanted to go to fragment 2 from fragment 1, I use basiClickListeners.goToFragment2() from fragment 2, and it works.

I don't know why sometimes I am getting NPE on basicClickListeners. Even though the fragment is active, how can the basicClickListeners become null? And it's not happening always. Only sometimes. I couldn't identify a pattern on why it's occurring. Kindly assist me with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onAttach()` and `onDetach()` overridden method in `Fragment` for registering and clearing the interface listeners. Also, make sure that the interface is implemented in your activity. Then, you can use `mCallback` reference for calling the `goToFragment2()`, `goToFragment3()` methods.

**YourFragment**

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            mCallback = (BasicClickListeners) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement BasicClickListeners");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        mCallback = null;
        super.onDetach();
    }
}
```

**YourActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
implements BasicClickListeners {

}
```